# Click once an error occured attemptin to install program

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I am trying to publish my application using clickonce. However when application is published and when going on page, download setup after run it i get simply message as below. What can i doto repair that? It seems it something with certificate. My serwer contains SSL certificate is it something related?

```
An error occured attempting to install MyPogram
```

when look at log file i see this:

```
   PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.14393.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1637.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1586.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.14393.0 (rs1_release.160715-1616)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : http://serwer1598052.home.pl/probix/Probix.application
                        Server      : IdeaWebServer/v0.80
    Deployment Provider url     : http://serwer1424786.home.pl/probixmain/Probix.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of http://serwer1598052.home.pl/probix/Probix.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Downloading http://serwer1424786.home.pl/probixmain/Probix.application did not succeed.
        + The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
        + The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [5/8/2017 12:51:08 PM] : Activation of http://serwer1598052.home.pl/probix/Probix.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [5/8/2017 12:51:08 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://serwer1424786.home.pl/probixmain/Probix.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException
        - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, Exception exception)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
            at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
            at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
            at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
            at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the signing certificate, it's invalid or expired.  Check your signing certificate.  There's more information  about this at the link below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff369721.aspx